# Написание расширения для Firefox

Tags: firefox

Где можно найти детальную инфу по написанию расширений для Firefox?

Хочу сделать собственное расширение по сокращению длинных ссылок, использующий мой же веб-сервис по сокращению. В принципе, там ничего волшебного, насколько я могу судить: отправка данных на сервер, получение результата, возврат результата в какое то окошко. Просто без понятия откуда подойти.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну [вот рядом есть](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) попроще.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/developers/) довольно исчерпывающая информация по вопросу.

Comment: Она там ну очень уж исчерпывающая ) мне бы более простыми и понятными словами что нибудь.